# javascript and java use the pubKey to encryption message

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

In RSA, I know the pubKey,I want to use the pubKey to encryption the message in javascript and java ,but the result is not right.
The JavaScript code is below:

```
    function getEntryptPwd(pwd){
    var pubKey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDC7kw8r6tq43pwApYvkJ5laljaN9BZb21TAIfT/vexbobzH7Q8SUdP5uDPXEBKzOjx2L28y7Xs1d9v3tdPfKI2LR7PAzWBmDMn8riHrDDNpUpJnlAGUqJG9ooPn8j7YNpcxCa1iybOlc2kEhmJn5uwoanQq+CA6agNkqly2H4j6wIDAQAB";
    if(!pwd || !pubKey || !SysConfig.encryptInfo){
        return pwd;
    }
    var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
    encrypt.setPublicKey(pubKey);
    return encrypt.encrypt(pwd);
}
```

I use the `getEntryptPwd("123456").length` method,the result is 172.
The java code is below:

```
        String publicKey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDC7kw8r6tq43pwApYvkJ5laljaN9BZb21TAIfT/vexbobzH7Q8SUdP5uDPXEBKzOjx2L28y7Xs1d9v3tdPfKI2LR7PAzWBmDMn8riHrDDNpUpJnlAGUqJG9ooPn8j7YNpcxCa1iybOlc2kEhmJn5uwoanQq+CA6agNkqly2H4j6wIDAQAB";
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    byte[] encodedKey = Base64.decode(publicKey);
    PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey));

    byte[] encrypt = encrypt(pubKey, "123456".getBytes("utf-8"));

    System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypt).length());
```

However,the output result is 176.
There must be something wrong ,i can not find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the old `sun.misc.Base64Encoder` and it is adding some extra line breaks. Replace it with `java.util.Base64` to get an output of 172

```
System.out.println(
      Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypt).length());
```